# Wordpress get_users timeout on big user database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a database in a Wordpress project with over 10000 users, I want to use get_users function to get all of them and then loop through each but I'm having timeout problems. If I pass to the function a limit number it works, but I need to get all the users.

```
//This works as expected
$Users = get_users(array( 'number' => '5000' ));
```

I thought about doing calls to the function by batches of 1000 using an offset value and adding the results to a main array with all the users but it won't work either. Does this make sense at all? Which would be the right solution to query long databases of users in Wordpress?

```
$totalUsers = count_users();
$batchSize = 1000;
$batchesCount = ceil($totalUsers['total_users'] / $batchSize);
$Users = array();

for ($count = 0; $count < $batchesCount; $count++) {
  $args = array(
    'number' => $batchSize,
    'offset' => $count * $batchSize,
  );
  $batchNewUsers = get_users($args);
  $Users = array_merge($Users, $batchNewUsers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 60

//; also, higher if you must - sets the maximum time in seconds
```

But 10000 is not to big number so thing about better VPS.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I'd actually prefer finding a way to optimize the fetching of the db registers, the number of users will keep growing and I'm not sure that increasing the max_execution_time will be a definitely solution.

Comment: So thing about caching results - for loop will never be good solution because it will always goes "live" through whole table. You can also create index for columns.